# Laravel Access forbidden on localhost xampp

Tags: apache, laravel, xampp, laravel-artisan

I just got stuck in the very begining. I have installed laravel and when i run php artisan serv command then this(Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/) line appears but when i access it through browser(http://localhost:8000/) then the following error gets displayed.

*Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.2*

Please help me out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am beginner in laravel.

Comment: So have you checked the file permissions of the php framework you installed? Can the http server process read those files? Because the error message clearly states that it can not, doesn't it?

Comment: yea it does. But I don't know how to check file permissions. where should i check it I mean there must be any command or something. How can I change the file permissions if my project path is  C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\laravel_project\blog>

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, didn't spot you use an MS-Windows environment. In that case file permissions are not the issue, those systems do not offer something comparable to that.

Comment: Yes I am using windows environment. So where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps below to create a virtual host:

Change to your XAMPP installation directory (typically, C:\xampp) and open the " httpd-vhosts.conf " and " httpd-xampp.conf " files in the apache\conf\extra\ subdirectory using your favourite text editor.
    Add these lines into both files with the following directives:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\laravel_project\blog"
       ServerName blog.dev
   <Directory "C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\laravel_project\blog">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews   
    AllowOverride all 
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

This contains two virtual host configuration blocks:

The first block is the default or fallback virtual host, which is used for all requests that are not matched by subsequent blocks.
The second block sets up a virtual host named wordpress.localhost. The DocumentRoot directive specifies the directory to be used when serving requests for this virtual host (in this case, the WordPress installation directory), while the ServerName directive specifies the custom domain name for the virtual host.

To add more virtual hosts, simply duplicate the second virtual host block and modify the port number, DocumentRoot and ServerName directives as per your requirements. For example, if you want to use SSL with your custom domain name, you can add a new virtual host block for port 443.
        If you plan to have a large number of virtual hosts with very similar configuration, consider using wildcard-based subdomains with your virtual hosts.

Restart Apache using the XAMPP control panel for your changes to take effect.

At this point, your virtual host is configured. However, if you try browsing to the wordpress.localhost domain, your browser will show a failure notice, since this domain does not exist in reality. To resolve this, it is necessary to map the custom domain to the local IP address. To do this, open the file C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add the following line to it:

```
127.0.0.1           blog.dev
```

This takes care of mapping the wordpress.localhost domain name to the local machine, which always has the IP address 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.I want to ask do i need to change DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/apps/laravelProject/public" ? I pasted your code in both the files as it is but doesn't seem to work for me. Also in win 8 its not letting me edit the ...etc/hosts file. it says Please check if this file is opened in another document.

Comment: Ok, give me the path to the xampp directory.
to edit etc/hosts, just copy it to another directory (desktop for example) and edit it, then replace it with the file in etc/hosts

Comment: I have  pasted this line(127.0.0.1           laravelProject.dev) in hosts file. And path to my xampp directory is C:\xampp

Comment: Good, give me the path to the public folder of your project

Comment: here is the path to my laravel project C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\laravel_project\blog

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I configured the virtual host as per your answer but it doesn't seem to work for me. when i navigate to blog.dev it says This webpage is not available. And on http://localhost/:8000/ its it says Access Forbidden and on http://localhost/ it gives me the list of files in my laravel project named blog. Any Idea where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you already have Apache running on port 8000.

Try running the serve command like this:
`php artisan serve --port=9000`

After it's running navigate to http://localhost:9000

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work. I changed the port and then again same issue server gets started but  when i navigate to http://localhost:9000 then it says You don't have permission to access the requested directory